# What is running loss in PyTorch and how is it calculated

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I had a look at [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html) tutorial in the PyTorch docs for understanding Transfer Learning. There was one line that I failed to understand.

After the loss is calculated using `loss = criterion(outputs, labels)`,  the running loss is calculated using `running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)` and finally, the epoch loss is calculated using `running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]`.

Isn't `loss.item()` supposed to be for an entire mini-batch (please correct me if I am wrong). i.e, if the `batch_size` is 4, `loss.item()` would give the loss for the entire set of 4 images. If this is true, why is `loss.item()` being multiplied  with `inputs.size(0)` while calculating `running_loss`? Isn't this step like an extra multiplication in this case?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's because the loss given by [`CrossEntropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) or other loss functions is divided by the number of elements i.e. the reduction parameter is `mean` by default.

```py
torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=None, size_average=None, ignore_index=-100, reduce=None, reduction='mean')
```

Hence, `loss.item()` contains the loss of entire mini-batch, but divided by the batch size. That's why `loss.item()` is multiplied with batch size, given by `inputs.size(0)`, while calculating `running_loss`.

Answer (score 10):

> if the batch_size is 4, loss.item() would give the loss for the entire set of 4 images

That depends on how the `loss` is calculated. Remember, `loss` is a tensor just like every other tensor. In general the PyTorch APIs return [avg loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) by default

> "The losses are averaged across observations for each minibatch."

`t.item()` for a tensor `t` simply converts it to python's default float32.

More importantly, if you are new to PyTorch, it might be helpful for you to know that we use `t.item()` to maintain running loss instead of `t` because PyTorch tensors store history of its values which might overload your GPU very soon.

Comment: "PyTorch tensors store history of its values which might overload your GPU very soon" - So, you're saying `t` is on the GPU memory and `t.item()` is on the CPU memory, right? If I am mistaken, can you explain it briefly?

Comment: `t.item()` retrieves the loss value (as a float) which lives on CPU, but the point is that `t` contains the aforementioned loss value AND the gradients, the latter of which are only relevant for backpropagation and therefore should not be kept when computing/storing the running loss. So this is relevant whether you are using CPU or GPU.